# Incomplete files when saved to database on iOS 7 device

Tags: xcode, core-data, ios7, nsmanagedobjectcontext, large-files

I have an App which downloads in a loop small and bigger files into core data (Attribute Type: Binary Data, Option: **allows external storage**). This always worked fine, but since iOS 7 I have some larger files (e.g. pdfs from 10 Mb and more) which are not completely saved anymore.

It looks like saving the managed object context is now asynchronous and that saving these files is interrupted by some of my next commands.

I could simulate it with resetting the context (MOC) after saving (this to prevent memory issues). Also when working with a main and child context I have this issue. In the child context I write the file into the database.

Is there a way to make sure the save is done?

Remarks: 
I don't have this behaviour when running on the simulator, only on a real device wit iOS 7.
When I don't set the property "Allows external storage" the savings takes longer but then it works.

Comment: Please explain "not completely saved".

Comment: Did you end up fixing the problem? I have a very similar issue. Works fine on the simulator, but no go on the device. I think the changes in iOS 7 has something to do with it.

Comment: I don't put any big files in database anymore. Only the path to the file is saved.